# Create mesh from point cloud

Tags: mesh

I would like to create a *smooth* mesh from a point cloud. As an example, let's create a bunch of points from the Hénon-Heiles system

```
sol = First@NDSolve[{x'[t] == p1[t], y'[t] == p2[t], 
                     p1'[t] == -x[t] - 2 x[t] y[t], p2'[t] == -x[t]^2 - y[t] + y[t]^2, 
                     x[0] == -.1, y[0] == -.2, p1[0] == .25723, p2[0] == -.05}, {x, y, p1, p2}, 
                     {t, 0, 4000}];
```

using Mathematicas build in adaptive sample algorithm

```
pnts = {}; ParametricPlot3D[pnts = Append[pnts, Evaluate@{x[t], y[t], p2[t]} /. sol]; 
                            Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], p2[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 4000}, 
                            PlotPoints -> 1000];
```

To get a 3D plot, the obvious choice seems to be

```
 ListSurfacePlot3D[pnts, MaxPlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False]
```

which generates the following graphic

[image]

Here, the "thin" parts of the donut shaped object are jagged. How can one make it smoother?

Comment: I think this could be done with a concave hull. ``sample = RandomSample[pnts, 8000]; b = ResourceFunction["NonConvexHullMesh"][sample, .05]``. Those seams still seem a bit problematic: ``Show[b, ListPointPlot3D[sample, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[.01]}]]``. However, looking at this combined plot makes me think that the problem lies in the points-generating stage. Perhaps it might help increasing the precision of ``NDSolve`` or somehow get more samples around the seams.

Comment: You should use Reap/Sow instead of Append so you don't have to keep setting pnts. Have you considered making a 3D density and then doing a ContourPlot3D to extract a level set of the density? That would be smoother than building a mesh which is always non-smooth unless it's flat.

Comment: For the above Reap/Sow: ```pnts = First@Last@Reap@ParametricPlot3D[Sow[Evaluate@{x[t], y[t], p2[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 4000},PlotPoints -> 1000];```

Comment: @flinty Thanks for the alternative to `Append` . 
Would you mind to go into more detail (as I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean)?

Comment: @Domen Unfortunately I can't reproduce your results as ResourceFunction isn't implemented in my version of mathematica (11.3).

Comment: @freddy90 Nevermind, I tried this approach and the result is too 'blobby'